# How do I change the Z-Order of sprites?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, z-order

I want to set the Z-order of the sprites I create in Objective-C, specifically in Cocos2D.

This is the error I get when trying to build the following code:

```
CCSprite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Image.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 96, 24)]; 
mySprite.zOrder = 0;
```

`...220: error: object cannot be set - either readonly property or no setter found`

Z-Order must be able to be set somehow - can it only be set on the line of instantiation and not after it's been created? Do I have to create a setter method for an attribute for CCSprite? Why wouldn't it already have those methods?

Answer (score 39):

If you need to reorder after adding the sprites, as GamingHorror said, use:

```
[self reorderChild:sprite z:newZ];
```

Your answer works if all you need is to set the original order

Answer (score 6):

Figured it out:

When adding the sprite to self, need to add a parameter:

```
CCSprite *mySprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"mySpriteImage.png" rect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 96, 24)];

[self addChild:mySprite z:1];
```

z = 0 is background, the highest z index will be on top of the other sprites

-JJR

Comment: you can also use reorderChild method to change its z order on the fly

Answer (score 1):

```
_background.name = @"background";
[self addChild:_background];
_background.zPosition =-5;
```

check out the z position at last line ,i hope this will help you